# Using regex to replace the punctuation marks and use minimum length of words

Tags: java, regex

I have a number of `String`s like:

```
String str = "camera+app,mountain,lord+kelvin,man,square+format,+-+,sea,e2";
```

and I want to create a new `String` which:

1. will have all punctuation marks replaced by single space and
2. also the words are going to be larger or equal than 3 characters

The desired output should be: 
`camera app mountain lord kelvin man square format sea`, so I figured a regex might do the trick.

I tried

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?\\p{Punct})?([\\w]]{3,}*)(?\\p{Punct})?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
int i = 1;
if(matcher.matches()) {
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print(matcher.group(i++) + " ");
    }
}
```

which obviously does not work properly (as you expect from this post).

To express my point of view:

- I put `(?\\p{Punct})?` as an optional non-capturing punctuation mark
- Then `([\\w]]{3,}*)` is supposed to capture the desired substring and
- The final `(?\\p{Punct})?` is to capture any following punctuation.

I guess this does not take care of multiple punctuation marks but I guess to deal with this later.

I always have some trouble with regex and so I am bit stuck.
When I import my regex in [enter link description here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) I get a peculiar error (at least to me) about `Unknown inline modifier near index 2` which is `\\`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is not working because your regex is faulty. You can use this regex:

```
\p{Punct}*(\w{3,})\p{Punct}*
```

Also note this *corrected code*:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}*(\\w{3,})\\p{Punct}*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " ");
}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vE8wY3/1)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue (from your input/output), you can simply replace punctuation with a 1+ quantifier with one single space:

```
String str = "camera+app,mountain,lord+kelvin,man,square+format,+-+,sea";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", " "));
```

**Edit (I)**

If you want to limit the size of the words picked up by `replaceAll`, you can use the following sequential replacement. Note that this is not as elegant, nor does it perform as well as a single replacement;

```
System.out.println(
    str.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+|\\b\\w{1,2}\\b", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
);
```

**Output**

```
camera app mountain lord kelvin man square format sea
```

**Notes**

- Due to the complexity of your attempt, I suspect you have missed some specification in your desired behavior... my answer looks way too easy! However, it **does** return your desired output.
- You can also itemize the result of your replacement into an `array`. For instance:

  ```
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("\\p{Punct}+")));
  ```

  **Edit (II)**
  To limit the size of the words while itemizing the elements, you can use the following pattern:

  ```
  System.out.println(
      Arrays.toString(str.split("(^|\\W+?)\\w{1,2}(\\W+?|$)|\\p{Punct}+"))
  );
  ```

  **Output**

  ```
  [camera, app, mountain, lord, kelvin, man, square, format, sea]
  ```

Comment: Well, I have though a `replaceAll` approach but it does not answer the question about the word length.

Comment: @Epyros maybe that's what I haven't understood. You state "also the words are going to be larger or equal than 3 characters". Does that mean that you want to filter out words smaller than 3 characters? In which case, you should probably correct the input string in your question by adding some < 3 character words.

Comment: Yeah, I might have to do that to be more accurate

Comment: thanks for your answer but your approach seems to fail to handle cases like: `m%C3%A1ty%C3%A1s,matthias`. Anyway the solution of @anubhava seems to work smoothly so I can proceed.

Comment: @Eypros yes anubhava's answer looks more elegant in my opinion. Leaving mine just to illustrate alternative solutions, although it might fail for some edge cases.